# "Span" Selector not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a border around my H1 but for some reason i can't select the exact "span" in css? Have i written something incorrectly?

HTML

```css
    h1 span {
    
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0.5em
      border: white solid 10px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="octopus.png">
  </div>

  <nav>
    <a href="">One</a>
    <a href="">One</a>
    <a href="">One</a>
    <a href="">One</a>
  </nav>
  <h1><span>Elias</span></h1>
  <p class="kicker">Stuff // Other Stuff // More</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a `;` after the `padding`, which won't let `border` work

```css
h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: white solid 10px;
}
/*demo*/

body {
  background: lightblue
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="">One</a>
  <a href="">One</a>
  <a href="">One</a>
  <a href="">One</a>
</nav>
<h1><span>Elias</span></h1>
<p class="kicker">Stuff // Other Stuff // More</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
span.classy {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="classy">Here's a span with some text.</span>
<span>Here's another.</span>
```